# Enumeration table, separate databases, readability and performance

Tags: database-design

I have this table called `Locales`. It's in the `Globalization` database:

```
Id  Key Description
1   en  English
3   ar  العربية
4   ru  Русский
```

I want to create a multi-lingual online shop. I have a `Products` table in the `Products` database, and for each record of the product, I should specify its language.

I came up with this design:

For clarity, I keep the `Key` of the `Locale` in the `Products` table, instead of its `Id`:

```
Id Title Locale
1  Desk  en
2  Phone en
3  هاتف  ar
```

For performance reasons, I allow databases to create views from each other. This increases coupling but reduces complexity. So I create a `ProductViews` view in the `Products` database, that refers to the `Locales` in the `Globalization` database (cross-database view).

```
create view ProductViews
as
select
    Products.*,
    Globalization.Locales.Id as LocaleId
from Products
inner join Globalization.Locales
on Products.Locale = Globalization.Locales.`Key`
```

This way if I want to select the `en` products, I don't have to query on a string column, and I can query on the `LocaleId` column from the view, thus in theory I should not have a performance issue.

But is that true? I still need to join over two tables to access `LocaleId`. And that join is done over two string columns.

Does that view give me performance benefit or am I just a naive developer complicating things?

**Update**: I'm using MariaDB 11.0.3. I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: You should tag your database system, version, and edition, as it's not really possible to answer a performance question without that information. (Seems like you might be using SQL Server?)

Comment: @J.D. updated the answer. Thanks for the note.

Comment: How about just trying this out. Fill your product table with dummy products - say 1 mio of them and create 100 locales. Then run your queries and see if the response time matches your business requirements. With the proper indexes in place any relational database will handle that without any problem. Partitioning the product table (and its indexes) based on locale may be something to consider too.

Comment: IMO the real things to worry about in your case is scalability and the work done in the actual application, and how it connects to the database, i.e. how you manage the connection pool. So you should also test your database design under load with simulated concurrent users and think times based on your business needs.